# Resolution of LightDM an additional monitor - Elementary OS Freya

Tags: release-freya, display, resolution

How to fix this problem with the resolution of LightDM an additional monitor?

```
lightdm 1.10.5

    Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
    LVDS1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
       1280x800       60.0 +   50.0  
       1024x768       60.0  
       800x600        60.3     56.2  
       640x480        59.9  
    VGA1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
       1920x1080      60.0*+
       1680x1050      60.0  
       1600x900       60.0  
       1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
       1280x960       60.0  
       1280x800       59.8  
       1152x864       75.0  
       1280x720       60.0  
       1024x768       75.1     60.0  
       1024x576       60.0  
       832x624        74.6  
       800x600        75.0     60.3  
       640x480        75.0     60.0  
       720x400        70.1  
    HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    DP3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

[image]

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that this is a know bug.

Comment: There is a similar question on Ask Ubuntu, maybe it helps: ["How to force Multiple Monitors correct resolutions for LightDM?"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/119843/how-to-force-multiple-monitors-correct-resolutions-for-lightdm)

This is the report for unity-greeter on Launchpad: [Bug #1082952 "Lightdm does not display correct resolution in multimonitor setup"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/1082952)